# Change ngModel of input in ngModelChange

Tags: angular

I've got this in a template:

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="model" (ngModelChange)="cleanseModel($event)">
```

and then I've got something like this in the controller:

```ts
model: string;

cleanseModel(value: string) {
    this.model = value.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '').substr(0, 4);
}
```

Unfortunately, the input doesn't get cleansed! I enter `12345` and the input will have `12345`. I can put `{{model}}` in the template, and that does show correctly (ie `1234`), but the input eludes me.

**How can I update the input?**

Comment: You could do this: `<input [(ngModel)]="model" maxlength="4" >` (assuming that you really only want to limit the length of the string).

Comment: @ConnorsFan, I should have realized that would be the most straightforward answer. The cleanser is actually more complex. I'll elaborate in my question. Thank you though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **`this.`**

```
cleanseModel(value: string) {
    this.model = value.substr(0, 4);
}
```

UPDATE:

Try like this,

```
<input [ngModel]="model" name="carData" (input)="model = deleteInputStream($event)"/>
{{carData}} <br/>
```

and in component.ts

```
  deleteInputStream(data) {    
    return data.target.value = data.target.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '').substr(0, 4);
  }
```

**[`STACKBLITZ DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-keyup-txwrhw?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**